# jQuery - How do I use AND with Selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

My code's function is to alert user if the `ptype` textfield is empty.

```
$("input[name*='ptype']").each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "") {
                    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#feffe3'});
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("Enter Value!");
                }
            });
```

However, I need to add another criteria where another field `amount` is not 0. So that the function get triggered when `ptype="" && amount!=0`. I'm very new in jQuery, and I'm not sure how to use `AND` operator in here. I've tried to do some based on other questions but it seems not working.

> $("input[name*='ptype'][amount!='0']").each(function() {
>
> $("input[name*='ptype'] , [amount!='0']").each(function() {

What am I missing ?

Comment: post your HTML also to get to know the issue better

Comment: You just made it `ptype="" && amount!=0` using `&&`. Jquery is Javascript.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I just need to know how to use the `and` operator

Comment: @user3502626 it don't work like that, tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with **&&** sign. Code depends on where your amount field is located and what it is. If I guess right it should be something like this:

```
$("input[name*='ptype']").each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "" && $(this).parent().find(input[name='amount']).val() != 0) {
                    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#feffe3'});
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("Enter Value!");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

That code `$("input[name*='ptype'][amount!='0']").each(function() {` is valid. You have to check the [CSS selectors list](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_selectors.asp).

The problem maybe in your `*=` selection. `input[name*="ptype"]` means Selects every  element whose name attribute value contains the substring "ptype".

```
$('input[name*="ptype"][amount!="0"]').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "") {
                    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#feffe3'});
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("Enter Value!");
                }
            });
```

Take a look at this test https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/211871/

Comment: `amount` is an input name like `ptype`

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. If `amount` is not an attribute in the same `input[name*="ptype"]`, you should show your HTML form code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function in your button.

```js
function check(e){

    var verror = false;

    $("input[name*='ptype']").each(function(index, value) {
        var amount = $($("input[name='amount[]']").get(index)).val();
        var ptype = $(this).val();
        if(ptype.length <= 0 && amount.length > 0 ){
            verror = true;
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(verror){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Enter Value!");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    ptype: <input type="text" name="ptype[]">
    amount: <input type="text" name="amount[]" value="1"> <br>

    ptype: <input type="text" name="ptype[]">
    amount: <input type="text" name="amount[]" value="2"> <br>

    <button type="button" onclick="check(event)">Click</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

***« where another field»*** is the key in question.

So you need a selector to check if a selected element is empty and **another** element is not zero.

Holà!

Logic problem here.
with `$(selector)` you can look up for some elements.

There is no AND / OR in selectors for many sets of matching element.
A selector is **ONE** set of matching elements.

No way this selector can check for an attribute `value` of another set.

So you have to know your markup and navigate a bit... **And** take care of variable types.

```js
$("input[name*='ptype']").each(function() {
  if ( parseInt( $(this).next("input").val() ) != 0) {
    $(this).css({"background-color" : "red"});
    alert("Enter Value!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

ptype: <input type="text" name="ptype"><br>
amount: <input type="text" name="amount" value="1">
```

You have to look **for another element's value** here, from my understanding. So you have to know what is that "other" element and the methods to use may vary a lot depending on your HTML...